# Upper bound estimation for second-order variable-coefficient ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

I'm tackling a second-order linear ordinary differential equation with variable coefficients $a(t)$ and seek advice on estimating the upper bound of
$y(t)$ s.t $|y(t)|\le M$. The equation in question is:
$$
    {y}''(t) + a(t) y(t) = 0,
$$
with the initial conditions $y(0)=m$ and $y'(0) = n$. Given that $t$ lies in the interval $[0, t]$, and both coefficient ${a}'(t)>0$ and $a(t)>0$, how can I estimate the upper bound $M$ of $y(t)$? Any guidance on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**Attempt 1**
Let's consider the expression $y'^2 + ay^2$. The derivative of this expression with respect to time $t$ is given by:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(y'^2+ay^2) = a'y^2
$$
Now, if we assume $a(t) > 0$ and $a'(t) > 0$, it follows that:
$$
ay^2 \leq y'^2 + ay^2 = \int_{0}^{t} a'(s)y^2(s) \, ds + y'^2(0) + a(0)y(0)^2
$$
Subsequently, we infer that:
$$
ay^2 \leq \int_{t_1}^{t} a'(s)y^2(s) \, ds + n^2 + a_{0}m^2
$$
The terms $n^2 + a_{0}m^2$ seem to serve as a bound. However, a more precise estimate of $y(t)$ or its behavior is not readily attainable. The analysis provides an upper bound for $ay^2$ but does not close on a specific solution for $y(t)$.

**Attempt 2(Numerical Perspective)**

For example, $a(t) = t + 0.1$, $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$, We can see from the graph below that $y(t)$ is upper bounded by no more than $3$, so I guess that for the more complex coefficients $a(t)$, if it is greater than $0$ and $a'(t)>0$, then the solution to this differential equation is upper bounded. I'm looking up some literature to corroborate this, which seems to go through the sturm comparison theorem. Thank you very much for any ideas.

[Solution of y(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD9TA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify notations, assume that $t_1=0$. By shifting, this does not diminish generality. Also, without loss of generality (wlog) consider the ODE
$$y''+ay=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
on the entire interval $[0,\infty)$. Let $T_0:=0$ and then let
$$T_k:=\inf\{t>T_{k-1}\colon y(t)=0\};$$
here and in what follows, $k=1,2,\dots$.
By Corollary 1 in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-27407-8_26) or its [preprint version](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZF1Sk0ZgwHa9bQCBGQHE4FOsVTGdX8NY6ok), $0<T_1<T_2<\cdots<\infty$ (and actually $T_k-T_{k-1}\le\pi/\sqrt{a(0)}$). The setting in the mentioned paper is more general than yours and notations are different from yours: there, instead of the ODE \eqref{1}, we have the differential inequality
$$x''(t)-2a(t)x'(t)+[a(t)^2+b(t,x(t))^2]x(t)\le0. \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Let
$$y_k:=\max\{|y(t)|\colon T_{k-1}\le t\le T_k\}.$$
Then, in view of formula (13) in the mentioned paper,
$$y_1\le y_*:=\sqrt{m^2+n_+^2/a(0)},$$
where $n_+:=n$ if $mn\ge0$ and $n_+:=0$ if $mn<0$; here we also used the condition that $a(\cdot)$ is increasing.

Next (cf. the first displayed formula in the consideration of Case 2 in the proof of Theorem 1 in the mentioned paper),
$$y'(T_1)^2-n_-^2\le a(T_1)y_1^2,$$
where $n_-:=0$ if $mn\ge0$ and $n_-:=n$ if $mn<0$.
So, again in view of formula (13) in the mentioned paper and because $a(\cdot)$ is increasing,
$$y_2\le\sqrt{y(T_1)^2+y'(T_1)^2/a(T_1)}
=\sqrt{0^2+y'(T_1)^2/a(T_1)}
\le\sqrt{0^2+(n_-^2+a(T_1)y_1^2)/a(T_1)}
=\sqrt{y_1^2+n_-^2/a(T_1)}
\le\sqrt{y_*^2+n_-^2/a(0)}
=\sqrt{m^2+n^2/a(0)}
=:Y,$$
and $Y\ge y_1$.
Similarly,
$$y'(T_2)^2-0^2\le a(T_2)y_2^2$$
and hence
$$y_3\le\sqrt{y(T_2)^2+y'(T_2)^2/a(T_2)}
=\sqrt{0^2+y'(T_2)^2/a(T_2)}
\le\sqrt{0^2+a(T_2)y_2^2/a(T_2)}
=y_2\le Y.$$
Similarly,
$$y_{k+1}\le y_k\quad\text{for all $k\ge2$}\tag{3}\label{3}$$.

Thus,
$$\max_{t\ge0}|y(t)|=\max\{k\ge1\colon y_k\}
\le Y=\sqrt{m^2+n^2/a(0)}.$$

This upper bound on $|y|$ is exact for any given triple $(m,n,a(0))$: this bound is "attained in the limit" when $a(t)=a(0)$ for all real $t$ and hence $y(t)=m\cos(t\sqrt{a(0)})+n\sin(t\sqrt{a(0)})/\sqrt{a(0)}$.

---

To illustrate the decreasing oscillations (as stated in \eqref{3}), here are the graphs $\{(t,y(t))\colon0\le t\le10\}$ for the solutions $y$ of the ODE $y''(t)+(1+t)y(t)=0$ with the initial conditions $y(0)=m$ and $y'(0)=n$ for $m=1,n=5$ (left, with $mn>0$) and for $m=1,n=-5$ (right, with $mn<0$):

[image]

Comment: It seems my calculations might be slightly different. I will double-check them. Thank you for your kind assistance!

Comment: @lming2 : I now seems that the bound in your answer is the same as in mine.

Comment: @lming2 : Do you have a further response to my answer?

Comment: I read your answer and found it very helpful, so thank you very much. Later, I pondered a more complex problem, such as whether the integral of a(t) over [0,t] being greater than $c>0$(means $a(t)$ may be zero at some time), without insisting that a(t) is greater than 0, could lead to estimating an upper bound for the solution |y(t)| of the second-order differential equation? I thought about it for a long time and momentarily forgot to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $y'^2+a y^2$, for which derivative is
$$ \frac{d}{d t}(y'^2+a y^2) = a' y^2 $$
If $a(t)>0$ and $a'(t)>0$, we have
$$ a y^2 \leq y'^2+a y^2 = \int^t_{0} a'(s)y^2(s)ds + y'^2(0)+a(0) y(0)^2 $$
thus
$$ a y^2 \leq  \int^t_{t_1} a'(s)y^2(s)ds + n^2 + a_{0} m^2. $$
Applying Gronwall's inequality leads to
$$
y^2 \leq \frac{n^2+a_0m^2}{a}exp(\int_0^t \frac{a'}{a}ds) = \frac{n^2+a_0 m^2}{a_0}
$$
Obviously
$$
y\leq \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{a_0}+ m^2}
$$

Comment: Nice trick! Some typos here, though.

Comment: I guess you consider $y'^2+ay^2$ and apply Gronwall to $ay^2$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you so much for the reminder! I really appreciate it! $y'^2+ ay $ should be $y'^2+ ay^2$, i made a mistake when typing it on the computer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you very much! I've revised my answer.